# Trying to build a bot that listens for it's own name to be tagged

Tags: reddit

I've been playing with the reddit API and I'd really like to make a bot that listens for someone to tag it in a comment, and then responds with a comment.

I've been looking through the docs [here](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) but haven't found what I'm looking for.

I've seen other bots do this in the past so I feel it must be possible.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PRAW (Python Reddit API Wrapper), then you can use the redditor.inbox class to track "mentions". http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit/inbox.html?highlight=Mentions

Otherwise, AFAIK mentions are just another item in your inbox.

https://reddit.com/r/redditscripting

Comment: Awesome I'll give this a try. Thanks!